# Powershell - monitoring new processes with ExecutionPath and CommandLine

Tags: powershell, monitoring

I wonder if you can assist me with a script (as per title)

So I've been playing around with the code below:

```
Register-CimIndicationEvent -ClassName Win32_ProcessStartTrace -SourceIdentifier "ProcessStarted"
```

The output with `Get-Event` returns what I need:

```
Get-Event | select timegenerated, @{N='ProcessName'; E = {$_.sourceeventargs.newevent.processname}}
TimeGenerated         ProcessName           
-------------         -----------           
21-Feb-20 12:58:29 PM UpdateTrustedSites.exe
21-Feb-20 12:58:31 PM backgroundTaskHost.exe
21-Feb-20 12:58:33 PM pwrgate.exe           
21-Feb-20 12:58:33 PM chrome.exe
```

But I have no idea how to join it with win32_Process (Get-WMIObject win32_Process).CommandLine and .ExecutablePath)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Register-CimIndicationEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/register-cimindicationevent?view=powershell-7)

> The Register-CimIndicationEvent cmdlet subscribes to indications using an indication class name or a query expression. Use the SourceIdentifier parameter give a name to the subscription

And the SourceIdentifier parameter you are using is `Win32_ProcessStartTrace`.

[Win32_ProcessStartTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/krnlprov/win32-processstarttrace)
It only has the following properties you can access

```
[AMENDMENT]
class Win32_ProcessStartTrace : Win32_ProcessTrace
{
  uint8  SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR[];
  uint64 TIME_CREATED;
  uint32 ProcessID;
  uint32 ParentProcessID;
  uint8  Sid[];
  string ProcessName;
  uint32 SessionID;
};
```

That said, if you want to look up the Command and the Path for the process, you will have to look up the process information separately for each process.

```
foreach($event in Get-Event) {
    $TimeGen = $event.timegenerated
    $ProcessName = $event.sourceeventargs.newevent.processname
    $Process = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "Name LIKE '$ProcessName'" | select -First 1
    $ProcessCMD = ($Process | select CommandLine).CommandLine
    $processPath = ($Process | select ExecutablePath).ExecutablePath
    $out = [pscustomobject]@{
        Time=$TimeGen
        Name=$ProcessName
        Path=$processPath
        Command=$ProcessCMD
    }
    $out
}
```

You can combine the `$out` paramter by use of an array or hashtable and query that further as you need.

Comment: Thanks! It was exactly what i was looking for.:)